# play 2.3.10 and Scala 2.11.8

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm experiencing these compilation errors. It has been working for other projects but not for other ones. Any ideas? (I've already tried "Invalidate caches/restart")

```
warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.3.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.0: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 22, 2017 5:09:59 PM
```

My build.sbt is:

```
lazy val app = project.in(file("."))

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  json,
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.2.0" % "test"
)
```

My plugins.sbt is:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")
```

Comment: can you show us your build.sbt file

Comment: BTW the latest 2.3.x release for Scala 2.11 is 2.3.11 : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe.play%7Cplay_2.11%7C2.3.10%7Cjar (recommanded to upgrade to 2.5.x or event to 2.6.x)

Answer (score 0):

From my guess since you did not show us your build.sbt you need to add a resolver since the play version you use is not in the central repository

for the play framework you are using you need to add this line in your build.sbt

`resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"`

or if better update it to a newer version where the central repository have the dependency

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.6.3"
```

Comment: Rather use the cross version syntax with `%%` to specify the Scala dependencies : `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.3"`

Comment: I've added this line but it doesn't work:
     `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.3.10"`

Comment: Try building the program with the command like `sbt clean run` or you are using a version that does not exist